# How to create pager view with lots of images

Tags: java, android, android-studio, scrollview

I'm developing an application that reads a book contains 600 images, each page is an image with jpg extension loaded in the project resources folder,(for example p1.jpg , p2.jpg ...) the user can scroll left and right through the book .. How to accomplish this or is there a way to load only few images each time user reaches them?
Thanks

Comment: Create a view pager that extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` so you wont load a lot of memory within the devide to prevent OOM.

Comment: Well you would never want to load 600 of anything at once. You just need to set a reasonable offscreen page limit, and the view pager will take care of loading/unloading for you.